# Can't change sample rate Ubuntu Studio 20.04

Tags: pulseaudio, ubuntu-studio, jack

I had a hibernation disaster and was forced to power cycle the laptop. It was still powered on, but the screen was blank. Nothing would wake it up.

After power cycle, Carla only shows `44100` for the sample rate, no other choices. Ubuntu Studio Controls and QjackCtl show `48000`, among all the other usual options.

But if I open a `48000` project in Ardour I get a sample rate mismatch error. I tried calling out `48000` as the default sample rate in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` and that did not help.

Any assistance greatly appreciated as I cannot open any of my `48000` projects now ....

Comment: Any progress on this? Got the same issue. Starting jack in QjackCtl would show up `48000` in Carla, but midi connections not available.